# nonzeros in csr_matrix in scipy.sparse matrices

Tags: python, scipy

There is a nonzero() method for the csr_matrix of scipy library, however trying to use that function for csr matrices result in an error, according to the manual that should return a tuple with row and colum arrays. Any ideas on this problem?

Best regards,
Umut

Answer (score 1):

Umut, could you provide a code snippet?  The following works for me:

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse
x = sparse.csr_matrix([[1,0,1],[0,1,0]])
x.nonzero()
```

and yields

```
(array([0, 0, 1], dtype=int32), array([0, 2, 1], dtype=int32))
```

This is for the latest development version of scipy (you can check by printing `scipy.__version__`).

Comment: Hmm Thanks Stefan, I installed SciPy and NumPy from Debian repositories and the version is 

>>> scipy.__version__
'0.6.0'

I guess that is the problem. I see also the comment from J.F.Sebastian that it works for 0.7.0 so it seems that this functionality is not available in my version